# Session will not show new values

Tags: php, session

I have been trying to get my session update, I have created a basic update with mysql as well, it updates in the sql database but it will not show the change within the page.
I'm not sure what else to check, because I checked within the chrome settings and it does show a php session id value but if I go into session storage it shows nothing.
transaction.php

```
<?php
$_title = 'Update profile';
require_once(__DIR__.'../../components/header.php');
session_start();
if(! isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    header('Location: ../sign_in/sign_in.php');
    die();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION["lang"])) { $_SESSION["lang"] = "en"; }
if (isset($_POST["lang"])) { $_SESSION["lang"] = $_POST["lang"]; }


require_once(__DIR__.'../../globals.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'../../db.php');

try{
    $db = _db();
}catch(Exception $ex){
    _res(500, ['info'=>'System under maintainance','error'=>__LINE__]);
}

$userProduct = $_SESSION['user']['user_id'];

$q = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :userID');
$q->bindValue(":userID", $userProduct);

$q->execute();
require "../lan/lang." . $_SESSION["lang"] . ".php";

?>



<form class="style_form" id="update_profile" onsubmit="return false">

<div>
        <label for="name"><?=$_TXT[63]?></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['user_name']?>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="last_name"><?=$_TXT[64]?></label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['lastName']?>">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="email"><?=$_TXT[65]?></label>
      <input name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['email']?>" type="text">

<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['user_id'] ?>">

  <button onclick="update()" id="updateButton"><?=$_TXT[60]?></button>  

    
</form>
</section>


<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'../../components/footer.php');
?>
```

api-transaction.php

```
<?php 
require_once(__DIR__.'../../globals.php');
// Validate name
if( ! isset( $_POST['name'] ) ){ _res(400,['name is required']); }
if( strlen( $_POST['name'] ) < _FRIST_NAME_MIN_LEN ){ _res(400,['name min '._FRIST_NAME_MIN_LEN.' characters']); }
if( strlen( $_POST['name'] ) > _FRIST_NAME_MAX_LEN ){ _res(400,['name max '._FRIST_NAME_MAX_LEN.' characters']); }

// Validate last_name
if( ! isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ){ _res(400,['last_name is required']); }
if( strlen( $_POST['last_name'] ) < _LAST_NAME_MIN_LEN ){ _res(400,['last_name min '._LAST_NAME_MIN_LEN.' characters']); }
if( strlen( $_POST['last_name'] ) > _LAST_NAME_MAX_LEN ){ _res(400,['last_name max '._LAST_NAME_MAX_LEN.' characters']); }

// Validate email
if( ! isset( $_POST['email'] ) ){ _res(400,['email is required']); }
if( ! filter_var( $_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ){ _res(400,['email is invalid']); }

$db = require_once(__DIR__.'../../db.php');
try{
    session_start();
    // $userid = $_SESSION['userId'];
    // $userid = $_SESSION['user']['user_id'];
    $userid = $_POST['userId'];


    $db->beginTransaction();

    //Change name
    $q = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET user_name = :update_Name WHERE user_id = :userid');
    $q->bindValue(':userid',$userid);
    $q->bindValue(':update_Name', $_POST['name']);
    $q->execute();

    //Change last name
    $q = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET lastName = :update_lastName WHERE user_id = :userid');
    $q->bindValue(':userid',$userid);
    $q->bindValue(':update_lastName', $_POST['last_name']);
    $q->execute();

    //change email
    $q = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET email = :update_email WHERE user_id = :userid');
    $q->bindValue(':userid',$userid);
    $q->bindValue(':update_email', $_POST['email']);
    $q->execute();

    // change phone number 
    $q = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET phone_number = :update_phone WHERE user_id = :userid');
    $q->bindValue(':userid',$userid);
    $q->bindValue(':update_phone', $_POST['phone_number']);
    $q->execute();

    $db->commit(); 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response = ["info" => "info has been updated"];
    echo json_encode($response);

    


}catch(Exception $ex){
    http_response_code(500);
    echo $ex;
    echo 'System under maintainance';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Put `session_start()` at the very top of these scripts, in case your remaining code has errors that are outputted. When that happens, session_start() has no effect, so put it first until you finish debugging or even just leave it at the top.

Comment: Your code shows lots of reading data from the session, but I don't see anywhere that you update the session. Please tell us which lines of your code you believe are responsible for updating the session? Also it's unclear how these two pieces of code interact - have you omitted some JavaScript which links them together, perhaps?